# 2 dimensional array sorting using column index

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

```
void sortarray(final int index){
        Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<Object[]>(){
            @Override
            public int compare(Object[] o1,  Object[] o2) {
                String[] a = (String[])o1;
                String[] b = (String[])o1;
                return a[index].compareTo(b[index]);
            }
        });

    }
2 5 LouieChef B 
2 6 Lawson C 
2 10 BakerSarah D 
2 11 SmothersSally A 
2 12 SillySall C 
2 13 Viper B
```

how to sort two dimensional string array on column index.
this code is not working ...

Comment: Is this a 2D array of strings? If it is, change the declaration; if it is not, change the cast.

Comment: means change object to string ??

Comment: Change Object[] to String[][]. Could you please also clarify what kind of sorting you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code should work

```
String[][] theArray = new String[][]{{"Enter values","Enter values"}, {more values, more values}};
Comparator<String[]> comparator= new Comparator<String[]>() {
       Arrays.sort(theArray, new Comparator<String[]>(){
                @Override
                public int compare(String[] o1,  String[] o2) {
                    return o1[0].compareTo(02[0]);
                }
            });
 Arrays.sort(theArray, comparator);
```

Casting should always try to be avoided. Although it should work to use your approach (object and cast to string) so you probably have some other error in your code. Anyway, it's better to explicit tell the compiler that you are sorting Strings if you know that this is what you will be sorting.